# What is the difference beween adding a Module to World vs adding a Class in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

For example.

When working with ruby on rails in cucumber you can do both

**Example with a Class**

```
class Awesome
   def thing
   end
end

World{ Awesome.new }
```

**Example with a Module**

```
module Awesome
   def thing
   end
end

World(Awesome)
```

Why would I use one over the other? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

No difference because class's class is inherited from module's class. The only difference is that you can't instantiate the module. Usually in cucumber you don't need to do it so modules are just ok. If you somehow need to include something into the world and somewhere else you have to make an instance - you can go with class but I hardly can imagine such situation,